# Unable to install lwc-dev-server / run sfdx force:lightning:lwc:start

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I am trying to run LWC in local. I was able to install with errors

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server
Polling for new version(s) to become available on npm... done
Successfully validated digital signature for @salesforce/lwc-dev-server.
Finished digital signature check.
Installing plugin @salesforce/lwc-dev-server... - [2/4] Fetching packages...
warning "@salesforce/lwc-dev-server > request-promise-native@1.0.9" has unmet peer dependency "request@^2.34".
warning "sfdx-plugin-source-read > @salesforce/command > @oclif/test > @oclif/core > ts-node@10.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "@types/node@*".
warning "sfdx-plugin-source-read > @salesforce/command > @oclif/test > @oclif/core > ts-node@10.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.7".
Installing plugin @salesforce/lwc-dev-server... - [4/4] Building fresh packages...
(node:14016) TypeError Plugin: @salesforce/lwc-dev-server: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
module: @oclif/core@2.6.2
task: toCached
plugin: @salesforce/lwc-dev-server
root: C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\sfdx\node_modules\@salesforce\lwc-dev-server
See more details with DEBUG=*
Installing plugin @salesforce/lwc-dev-server... installed v2.11.0
```

while running I am getting following error.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfdx force:lightning:lwc:start
(node:20104) TypeError Plugin: @salesforce/lwc-dev-server: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
module: @oclif/core@2.6.2
task: toCached
plugin: @salesforce/lwc-dev-server
root: C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\sfdx\node_modules\@salesforce\lwc-dev-server
See more details with DEBUG=*
```

Is local development even supported in March 2023? Looks like abandoned project but would love to get some confirmation from Salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to overcome this by uninstalling Node v19.8.1 and installing Node v18.15.0.

Answer (score 1):

From your description and logs, it seems like a compatibility issue between sfdx plugin and oclif version.

Update the @oclif/core module to the latest version by running the command `npm install @oclif/core@latest`, and reinstall the `lwc-dev-server` plugin.

Alternative approach, try updating the sfdx cli `sfdx update` and reinstalling the plugin.

Comment: do you have this working on your machine? FWIW, I have tried all updates and nothing has worked.

Comment: Yes, I am using it on M2 Mac. I did run into issues related to node-gyp

Comment: @ roh777x, can you please let know what node version you are using? I suspect I really need to downgrade node in order to make this work.

Comment: I am using Node v18.3

Comment: thanks @ roh777x